# javascript---click copy the content to the clipboard

Tags: javascript

the following is the code. but it doesn't work. what's wrong with it? thank you.

```
      <head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>no title</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function copyToClipBoard(content){
 var clipBoardContent = ''; 
clipBoardContent = content;
 window.clipboardData.setData("Text",clipBoardContent);
 alert('have copied to the clipboard');
}
```

```
 <body>
<textarea rows="4" cols="60" id="url">www.example.com</textarea>
     <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="copyToClibBoard (document.getElementById   ('url').value);" />

</body>
```

Comment: `onclick="copyToClibBoard` should be `onclick="copyToClipBoard`

Comment: hi you might want to [refer on this past discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in Javascript.

Instead, you need to [use Flash](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/).

Comment: why i  cannot do this in Javascript? thank you