# How to get copy text to work on different divs?

Tags: javascript

I have a 'div' that copies the text and I can paste it somewhere else.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div>
        Positive Comments:
        <br/>
        <textarea id="txtArea" rows="3" name="txtCommentPositive#CurrentRow#">
            #reReplaceCommentpositive
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        Negative Comments:
        <br/>
        <textarea rows="3" name="txtCommentNegative#CurrentRow#">
             #reReplaceCommentnegative#
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="copy" onclick="copyText()" />
</div>
```

It works when it has one result since its getting the first div1, but when it has two or more results even if i click on the 'copy' it will copy the first text.
How can I get it that it will copy each div separately?

This is my javascript:

```
function copyText() {
    var copyDivText = document.getElementById('div1').innerText;
    var returnVal = window.clipboardData.setData('Text', copyDivText);
    alert(returnVal);

    document.getElementById('div2').innerText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
}
```

Comment: just a note: you do realize that `window.clipboardData` is [hardly cross-browser supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278408/window-clipboarddata-is-not-part-of-javascript)? Why are you using it instead of a common variable (asking out of interest)? Likewise, `innerText` [is again IE only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox).

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @gitaarlab yes i do and i only want it to for in IE , dont care for other browsers

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question countless times, suddenly it clicked: it *seems* like you want to use the code from `div1` as a 'pattern' that you can re-use.
However your javascript has currently just one div-**id** hard-coded.

I didn't know what to make of `div2` (from your function) so I changed that (*as example*) to a `textarea` (with `id` `clipboardText`) that will show you the text-content that was just copied to the clipboard.

For simplicity (staying in-line of what seems to be your current code-logic/style) I suggest that the button is a direct child of the div that it needs to get the `innerText` from. If this is the case (and we continue to use inline-script), you'd pass `this` (that refers to the button that was clicked) to the function. In the function you'd then simply get the `innerText` of the button's `parentNode`:

Javascript:

```
function copyText(t) {
    var copyDivText = t.parentNode.innerText;
    var returnVal = window.clipboardData.setData('Text', copyDivText);
    alert(returnVal);

    document.getElementById('clipboardText').value = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
}
```

HTML Body (note I added another 'pattern' with id `div2`, since that seemed inline with what I guess you are doing):

```
<textarea id="clipboardText"></textarea>
<hr>
<div id="div1">
    <div>
        Positive Comments:
        <br/>
        <textarea id="txtArea" rows="3" name="txtCommentPositive#CurrentRow#">
            #reReplaceCommentpositive
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        Negative Comments:
        <br/>
        <textarea rows="3" name="txtCommentNegative#CurrentRow#">
             #reReplaceCommentnegative#
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="copy" onclick="copyText(this);" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div>
        Positive Comments:
        <br/>
        <textarea id="txtArea" rows="3" name="txtCommentPositive#CurrentRow#">
            #reReplaceCommentpositive
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        Negative Comments:
        <br/>
        <textarea rows="3" name="txtCommentNegative#CurrentRow#">
             #reReplaceCommentnegative#
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="copy" onclick="copyText(this);" />
</div>
```

Hope this is what you intended with your question.

PS: if this *is* what you intended, note that a lot of people consider inline-scripts bad and when you dynamically attach your function you do not have to pass `this` anymore (since then `this` can be called directly inside your function).